# Query running very slow on big MongoDB db

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB db with a single rather large collection of documents (13GB for about 2M documents) sitting on a single server with 8GB RAM. Each document has a text field that can be relatively large (it can be a whole blog post) and the other fields are data about the text content and the text author. Here's what the schema looks like:

```
{
    text: "Last night there was a storm in San Francisco...",
    author: {
        name: "Firstname Lastname",
        website_url: "http://..."
    },
    date: "201403075612",
    language: "en",
    concepts: [
        {name: "WeatherConcept", hit: "storm", start: 23, stop: 28},
        {name: "LocationConcept", hit: "San Francisco", start: 32, stop: 45}
    ],
    location: "us",
    coordinates: []
}
```

I'm planning to query the data in different ways:

1. Full-text search on the "text" field. So let's say my text search query is q:

   ```
   db.coll.aggregate([
       {
           $match:{
               $text: {
                   $search:q
               }
           }
       }
   ])
   ```
2. Aggregate documents by author:

   ```
   db.coll.aggregate([
       {
           $project: {
               name: "$author.name",
               url: "$author.website_url"
           }
       },
       {
           $group: {
               _id: "$name",
               size: {
                   $sum:1
               },
               url: {
                   $first: "$url"
               }
           }
       },
       {
           $sort:{
               size:-1
           }
       }
   ])
   ```
3. Aggregate documents by concepts:

   ```
   db.coll.aggregate([
       {
           $unwind: "$concepts"
       },
       {
           $group: {
               _id: "$concepts.name",
               size: {
                   $sum:1
               }
           }
       },
       {
           $sort:{
               size:-1
           }
       }
   ])
   ```

These three queries may also include filtering on the following fields: date, location, coordinates, language, author.

I don't have indexes yet in place, so the queries run very slow. But since the indexes would be very different for the different ways I hit the data, does that rule out indexing as a solution? Or is there a way to index for all these cases and not have to shard the collection? Basically my questions are:

- What would be a good indexing strategy in this case?
- Do I need to create separate collections for authors and concepts?
- Should I somehow restructure my data?
- Do I need to shard my collection or is my 8GB single-server powerful enough to handle that data?

Comment: Don't actually see a query or an index plan in your question. Goes a long way towards an actual response.

Comment: I don't have one specific query plan, I can potentially query the data in a lot of different ways. I'm planning to do full-text search, so I would index on the text field. But I'm also going to do aggregate queries on the authors and concepts. Does that rule out indexing? Or is there a way to index for all these cases and not have to shard the collection? The database size shouldn't get much larger

Comment: It was just a suggestion. Otherwise you get answers like you just did. So maybe consider changing your question if you don't like that kind of informed response.

Comment: Following your suggestion, I updated my question. For the setup, right now I have 8GB of RAM, but I can potentially increase that.

Comment: Not really hardware or server performance forum here. Stack Overflow is about programming questions. Show a query or get shut down. Or accept the pretty silly answer that was given. We'll close it anyway because it is not useful.

Comment: Ok, give me a moment and I'll update the question with my schema and the different type of queries I'm planning to do

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50893/discussion-between-cwarny-and-neil-lunn)

Comment: Obviously indexing is very important and is the first thing you should do, but knowing your working set etc. is very important as well. https://twitter.com/nickytonline/status/454089721048621056 has a link/credit to a great blog post on scaling Mongo written by the developer who created the Python Mongo driver, Jesse Jiryu Davis.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any indexes on your collection?

Have a look at the following

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/indexes/

if you do have indexes make sure they are being hit by doing the following

```
db.CollectionName.find({"Concept":"something"}).explain();
```

You also need to give us more information about your setup. How much RAM does the server have? I've worked with a MongoDB that has 200GB sitting on 3 shards. So 13GB on 1 shouldn't be an issue

Comment: Thanks, testydonkey. I updated my question with a comment about indexing. About the setup: right now I have 8GB of RAM. I have to admit that I didn't check that before your comment, and it makes sense that queries would run slow on a 13GB collection sitting on a server with only 8GB of RAM. To how much should I increase my RAM? Also, what about the multiple ways I'm planning to hit the data (cf my updated question)? Does that rule out indexing?

Comment: You probably don't need more RAM. What I should have said is I've worked with a 200GB mongoDB running on a total of 24GB of RAM.

As long as your indexes fit into RAM you 'should' be ok. Indexing can be a bit of a dark art with mongoDB so some trial and error is usually the case. You will want to look into 'multi key' indexes

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-multikey/

You may even want to re-visit the object structure you are storing and see if you can make performance gain that way.